# mvc3 + jQuery validation: how to catch error or ok events

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, validation, unobtrusive-validation

I'm using MVC3 C# and I have a model with some data annotation (validation rules)

In my view.cshtml file I have a form with some complex logic that draw some figures using absolute coordinates over existing elements.

When user submit the form with incorrect data the jQuery check makes visible some fields of @Html.ValidationMessageFor(...)
And now user may correct data - and instant the @Html.ValidationMessageFor(...) messages dissapear.

So, this showing/hiding moves other page-elements and this movement breaks my absolute positioning and I need to invoke redraw function ( CorrectSizesAndPos(); ).

How can I catch these nasty highlite/unhigligt events?

For now:

1. I add the id to my form:

   ```
   @using (Html.BeginForm("Action1", "Controller1", FormMethod.Post, 
           new {id="VMCreateForm"}))
   ```
2. I add event to check data on submit:

   ```
   $("#VMCreateForm").submit(function () {
       if (true == $("#VMCreateForm").valid()) {
           $(":disabled").removeAttr('disabled'); //<-- I need this to transfer data to server from some disabled fields... 
       }
       CorrectSizesAndPos();
       return true;
   });
   ```
3. I can catch if form is not good before submit:

   ```
   $(document).ready(function () {
       $("#VMCreateForm").bind('invalid-form.validate',
           function (form, validator) {
               console.log('invalid-form.validate');
               CorrectSizesAndPos();
           }
       );
    });
   ```
4. I try to add some events also inside $("#VMCreateForm").validate({ .. }) but they did not invoked...

How can I catch when unobstrusive validation shows or hides validation messages?

Answer (score 0):

I did several tests and finally I found solution for my case. May be it is not optimal but here it is:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var existingValdiation = $("#VMCreateForm").validate();
        var Original_errorPlacement = existingValdiation.settings.errorPlacement;
        var Original_success = existingValdiation.settings.success;
        existingValdiation.settings.errorPlacement = function (error, element) {
            Original_errorPlacement(error, element);
            CorrectSizesAndPos();
            //console.log('errorPlacement'); //for test
        };
        existingValdiation.settings.success = function (label) {
            Original_success(label);
            CorrectSizesAndPos();
            //console.log('success'); //for test
        };
    })
```